# Mosquitto ACL default all users read to a topic

Tags: access-control-list, mqtt

I am trying to create a default access for all users unless specified in the ACL file.

I have allow_anonymous set to false. However, if a user is in the password file, I want that user to be able to have read access only to a specific topic. If I define a user rule in the ACL file, I want that to be used instead. I want to do this so any new passwords I create will have a default access. That way I don't have to add an entry in the ACL file for every new password I create.

Basically something like:

```
user * (wildcard, all users)

topic read some_topic

(and then I create rules if needed)

user admin1
topic readwrite #

user user1
topic read temps
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, it seems like if you define one user section in the acl, the default acls get overridden. What worked for me was to use the `pattern` keyword instead of the `topic` (described here [mosquitto.conf man page
acl section](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm44))

So your example acl would look like this:

```
# All users
pattern read some_topic

user admin1
topic readwrite #

user user1
topic read temps
```

Edit: **Note that this approach generates below warnings in my case**

`Warning: ACL pattern 'some_topic' does not contain '%c' or '%u'.`